# Drop rows from dataframe based on date index gives "KeyError: "[''column_name'] not found in axis""

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a new dataframe excluding the rows containing two dates, my date column is the index.

When I use

```
DF2 = DF.drop(DF.loc['03/01/2018':'03/02/2018'])
```

I get the error

```
KeyError: "['Column_name1' 'Column_name2'] not found in axis"
```

I've tried adding `axis = 0` to specify that I want to drop rows, but still get the same error

```
DF2 = DF.drop(DF.loc['03/01/2018':'03/02/2018'], axis = 0)
```

If I try and print the 'loc' it returns the rows as expected

```
print(DF.loc['03/01/2018':'03/02/2018'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your statement just need `.index` at the end. to do the slicing like this you need loc, but `drop` wants `index` as input.

```
DF2 = DF.drop(DF.loc['03/01/2018':'03/02/2018'].index)
```

If this doesn't work, then you should check the format of index (needs to be string the way you try to access it)

If index is in `datetime.date` format you could do it like this:

```
DF2 = DF.drop(DF.loc[dateimte.date(2018,3,1):datetime.date(2018,3,2)].index)
```

Comment: Just adding .index worked, thank you! :-)

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if you like it ;) btw, if my solution works for you, the solution of @Ynjxsjmh should also work for you. I guess you didn't copy pasted it right to your code (for example, between dates is a `,`, no `:` , easy to overlook)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say your date is the index, when you use `DF.loc['03/01/2018':'03/02/2018']`, you are locating the rows that are between `03/01/2018` and `03/02/2018`.

[`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) accepts index or column label, by default it accepts index label. You should use

```py
DF2 = DF.drop(['03/01/2018', '03/02/2018'])
# or
DF2 = DF[~DF.index.isin('03/01/2018', '03/02/2018')]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get different errors when I try those:-

DF2 = DF.drop(['03/01/2018', '03/02/2018'])
gives
KeyError: "['03/01/2018' '03/02/2018'] not found in axis"

DF2 = DF[~DF.index.isin('03/01/2018', '03/02/2018')]
gives
KeyError: 'Requested level (03/02/2018) does not match index name (Date)'

print(DF.loc['03/01/2018':'03/02/2018'])
seems to be searching on the dates in MM/DD/YYYY format, so does just return those two dates 01/03/2018 and 02/03/2018 which is why I tried to use this in the drop line.

Comment: @EllenCoggin What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with the drop function (without loc)

```
data.drop('column_name')
```

and it was giving me a similar indexing error. I still had the error after adding .index , but this kwarg fixed it.

```
data.drop(columns='column_name')
```